# Do mobile advertising networks see IDFA/GAID of users?

Tags: networking, idfa, google-advertising-id

Question is: can or not mobile ad networks (AdCash,Marvel,AirPush...) see IDFA/GAID of those users which are clicking on advertisement?
For example if network has publisher (any website). Does this network know details of users which do click?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, yes - they can. You can opt-out though, look in your settings